# Error when i try to parse XML

Tags: java, android

i am having some problems with my XMLParser it crashes before application opens. The error i get is:

**Error:**    `org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)`

**Here is my code for XMLParser:**

```
public class XMLParser {

    public XMLParser(){
    }

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url){
        String xml = null;

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return xml;
    }

    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try{
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;

        if(elem != null){
            if(elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for(child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()){
                    if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    public String getValue(Element item, String str){
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

}
```

**And in my main activity i call it like thath:**

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
```

So if you can help me what could be causing this problems.

Comment: please post the entire stack trace

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/pfkzL9hP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace tell's you exactly whats wrong: you shouldn't do network stuff on the UI thread.

Good fix: Don't do network stuff on the UI thread, use AsyncTask or others.

Quick fix: add this before your network stuff:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

See http://www.techblogistech.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-the-android-networkonmainthreadexception/

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`? You can't call network APIs (i.e. `httpClient.execute()`) on the main activity thread. Instead you need to run it in an `AsyncTask`. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) if you need help on how to accomplish this.